# Check the content of an input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and I have a form, when I try to retrieve the user information, it does not work correctly.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Register</span>
                <select name="register_as" id="dropdown">
                    <option value="none">Select One</option>
                    <option value="user">User</option>
                    <option value="designer">Designer</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label><span>Gender</span></label>
            <div class="form-radio-buttons">

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
                        <span>Male</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
                        <span>Female</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("form").submit(function (e) {

            //Check if gender has not been selected
            var gender = $(this).find('input[name="gender"]').val();
            if(!gender){
                alert('select a gender');
            }

            //Check if 'register_as' is equal to 'user' or designer
            var register_as = $("#dropdown").val();
            if(register_as!= 'user' | register_as!= 'designer'){
                alert('Register as user or designer');
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

When a user wants to register, he has to choose between `user` and `designer`. If what he chooses is different then we alert him.
Same as the gender, he has to choose between `male` and `female`.

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Comment: `it does not work correctly` - so what is your error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the radio group value you need to use `:checked` or you will get the first one all the time.

```
var gender = $(this).find('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
```

The boolean operator Javascript `&&`

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("form").submit(function (e) {

            //Check if gender has not been selected
            var gender = $(this).find('input[name="gender"]:checked').val(); 
            if(!gender){
                alert('select a gender');
            }

            //Check if 'register_as' is equal to 'user' or designer
            var register_as = $("#dropdown").val();
            if(register_as!= 'user' && register_as!= 'designer'){
                alert('Register as user or designer');
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Register</span>
                <select name="register_as" id="dropdown">
                    <option value="none">Select One</option>
                    <option value="user">User</option>
                    <option value="designer">Designer</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label><span>Gender</span></label>
            <div class="form-radio-buttons">

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
                        <span>Male</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
                        <span>Female</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added `.filter(':checked')` into gender checking and altered `|` to `&&` into the if condition of the combobox checking

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Register</span>
                <select name="register_as" id="dropdown">
                    <option value="none">Select One</option>
                    <option value="user">User</option>
                    <option value="designer">Designer</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label><span>Gender</span></label>
            <div class="form-radio-buttons">

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
                        <span>Male</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
                        <span>Female</span>
                    </label>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("form").submit(function (e) {

            //Check if gender has not been selected
            var gender = $(this).find('input[name="gender"]').filter(':checked').val();
            if(!gender){
                alert('select a gender');
            }

            //Check if 'register_as' is equal to 'user' or designer
            var register_as = $("#dropdown").val();
            if(register_as!= 'user' && register_as!= 'designer'){
                alert('Register as user or designer');
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```